# Pull to Refresh for new items in Swift

Tags: swift

I am trying to implement a pull to refresh functionality in a ViewController which contains a TableView. Currently, the TableView is displaying stories from a data source which contains the following stories
[A, B, C, D]

When I pull to refresh, I get three new stories from server : [D, E, F]
now I have to display the stories in this order [D, E, F, A, B, C]

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
        
    let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    refreshControl.addTarget(self, action:  #selector(loadItems), for: .valueChanged)
    self.refreshControl = refreshControl
}

@objc func loadItems() {
    // confused here
        
    tableView.reloadData()
    refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return alphabet.count
}
  
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = alphabet[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try the below to insert the items at

```
alphabet.insert(someValue, at: 0) // Adds someValue at 0th Index


alphabet.insert(contentsOf: ["D", "E", "F"], at: 0) // Adds contents of array at 0th index
```

Now try `tableView.reloadData()`

Comment: But please pay attention, I am adding the same object which is D on the existing array which has D also.

Answer (score 0):

@konya normally the data from api should not repeated. But if it has repeated data you can filter to remove it, for example:

```
        var a = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
        let b = ["D", "E", "F"]
        a.removeAll(where: {b.contains($0)})
        a.insert(contentsOf: b, at: 0)
```

And the result be like: ["D", "E", "F", "A", "B", "C"]